# Question regarding "Count the number of paths problem", is my reasoning correct?

Tags: combinatorics

Say we want to count the number of paths to make it from point A to point B, imagine you can only walk South and East, how many paths are there?

[image: grid]

My reasoning to solve this problem is as follows. First notice that every path from A to B has to go through one and only one of the points C and D. So if we count the amount of paths from A to C and multiply it by the amount of paths from C to B that will give us all the paths that go through point C, we can then do the same for point D and just add up the results. This is simple enough to do and the final result is 210+350=560 ways.

[image: grid2]

Curiously, I found another solution where the reasoning is as follows: Compute the number of ways to make it to point F from A, then compute the number of ways to go from E to B, multiply it with the previous result and then divide by 2 and you get the desired result: 20*56/2 = 560.

[image: grid 3]

I don't understand why this solution works, at least not in a general case. It seems to me that this solution would only work in cases where the amount of paths from A to C is equal to the amount of paths from A to D, or the amount of paths from C to B is equal to the amount of paths from D to B. If we pick an example where this is no longer the case, we can see that we get different results for my method and the second method:

[image: grid 4]

Now in this case, my method yields the result: 420 + 525 = 945
The alternate method now yields: 35*56/2 = 980

So which one of the two is correct? was my reasoning  correct and the second method only works for the first case because of the special conditions I laid out? or is the second method the right way to solve the problem? thanks in advance!

Comment: The first method is correct and is how I would have solved it as well.  As for the second proposed method, I see no justification for why it should have given a correct result and can not propose a fix for something so far from a correct train of thought.  If it gave the correct result in limited circumstances then it was a fluke.